# Exact meaning of 都 in 刚刚你的担忧，我都听见了?

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning, usage

In 李芳，实不相瞒，刚刚你的担忧，我都听见了。

What is the real meaning of 都？
Cause i think it can have the 都...了 pattern wich means "already" so the sentence can be translated as ：李芳 ,to be honest i already heard your worries a moment ago ,

But also just mean “all" so the translation could be: 李芳 ，to be honest i heard all of your worries a moment ago.

By the way 刚刚 is an adverb of time which in this sentence take the place of a noun of time , right?

Comment: 都= all ; 了 = already; to be honest I've heard all  the worries you have a moment ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 我都听见了。

The sentence can be interpreted either way.

1. I heard it ***all***.
2. I ***already*** heard it (there is no need to hide it, so save the effort).

So, context and the tone of speakers are key elements to determine the meaning.

And yes, 刚刚 is an adverb here.

Answer (score 0):

Like Dan says, context will reveal the actual meaning. From your sentence I would translate:

李芳，
Li Fang,
实不相瞒，
frankly
刚刚你的担忧，
your fretting just now,
我都听见了。
I overheard everything.

都：everything

Answer (score 0):

The use of 都 gives the sentence an emphatic effect. (2) sounds more forceful than (1):

1. 你的担忧, 我听见了。
2. 你的担忧, 我都听见了。

都 is the trace of a series of operations as follows:

- The predicative relation "[我][听见][你的担忧]" ([X][V][Y]) is envisaged.
- A sense of alterity is introduced at the level of X, V **or** Y (in accordance with the context).
- The sense of alterity is then eliminated, which has the effect of "consolidating" the predicative relation.

When the sense of alterity concerns X, we could have something like:

- 你们听见的坏消息，**我**都听见了。

Here, the sense of alterity comes from "You thought that I was excluded from 'having heard of the bad news', but actually I am no different from you all."

When the sense of alterity concerns V, we could have something like:

- 你不用隐瞒，你的担忧, 我都**听见**了。

Here, the sense of alterity comes from "You thought that I didn't know it (没听见), but actually I knew it."

When the sense of alterity concerns Y, we could have something like:

- 你做的坏事, 我**全**都知道了。(全 is purposely added here to avoid ambiguities).

Here, the sense of alterity comes from "You thought that I only knew a small quantity, but actually I knew all."